# Флаг закрытия SaveFileDialog WPF MVVM ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Есть проблема при работе с SaveFileDialog. По задумке, при сохранении файла вывожу модальное окно с текстом "Успешно сохранено", в противном случае "Не сохранено". В итоге при сохранении выводятся оба модальных окна. Если нажать "Отмена" или "Х", происходит аналогичное. Создал отдельный класс для окна открытия/сохранения. Во ViewModel вызываю методы и совершаю действия.
Интерфейс:

```
public interface IDialogService
{

    string FilePath { get; set; }
    void ShowMessage(string message);
    void ShowMessage(string message, string title, MessageBoxButton msButton, MessageBoxImage msImage);  

    bool OpenFileDialog();
    bool SaveFileDialog();  
}
```

Класс для открытия диалоговых окон:

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{


    public string FilePath { get; set; }


    public bool OpenFileDialog()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            FilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            return true;
        }
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != true)
            return false;
        return false;
    }


    public bool SaveFileDialog()
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            FilePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            return true;
        }
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != true)
            return false;
        return false;
    }


    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }


    public void ShowMessage(string message, string title, MessageBoxButton msButton, MessageBoxImage msImage)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, title, msButton, msImage);
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 private void ToggleGetImageExecute()
    {

        DialogService dialogService = new DialogService();

        if (dialogService.SaveFileDialog())
        {

            PhotoShootFrame = new Bitmap(PhotoShootFrame, photoWidth, photoHeight);
            PhotoShootGray.Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            PhotoShootFrame.Save(dialogService.FilePath + fileExtencion, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //PhotoShootGray.Save("1");
            dialogService.ShowMessage(photoSaveDone, messageBoxTitle, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }

        dialogService.ShowMessage(photoNonSave, messageBoxTitle, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
```

Ну и ToggleGetImageExecute отправляю в new RelayCommand(ToggleGetImageExecute);

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное как-то так:

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService
{


    public string FilePath { get; set; }


    public bool OpenFileDialog()
    {
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (!openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
        {
            ShowMessage("Не сохранено");
            return false;
        }

        FilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
        ShowMessage("Успешно сохранено");
        return true;      
    }


    public bool SaveFileDialog()
    {
        var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (!saveFileDialog.ShowDialog())
        {
            ShowMessage("Не сохранено");
            return false;
        }

        FilePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        ShowMessage("Успешно сохранено");
        return true;
    }


    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }


    public void ShowMessage(string message, string title, MessageBoxButton msButton, MessageBoxImage msImage)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, title, msButton, msImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Вы в своем коде пытаетесь показывать диалоги дважды. Каждый вызов `saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()` или `openFileDialog.ShowDialog()` пытается показать диалог. Чтобы избежать двойного показа и проблем с ним, показывайте один раз и сохраняйте результат в переменную. То есть вместо этого

```
public bool SaveFileDialog()
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        FilePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        return true;
    }
    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != true)
        return false;
    return false;
}
```

Попробуйте это

```
public bool SaveFileDialog()
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    var result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result  == true)
    {
        FilePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        return true;
    }
    if (result != true)
        return false;
    return false;
}
```

И, кстати, последнее условие вообще можно удалить

```
public bool SaveFileDialog()
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    var result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result  == true)
    {
        FilePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        return true;
    }       
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ!